# How to use more than one audio tag

Tags: html

when using more than one audio tag, is there a way to prevent one side from playing when it begins to play?

if i play t1.mp3, then stop playing t2.mp3, and if i play t2.mp3, then stop playing t1.mp3
so i always want to playing only one song on the page.

```html
<audio controls="" loop=""> <source src="t1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> </audio>
…
<audio controls="" loop=""> <source src="t2.mp3" type="audio/mp3"> </audio>
```

Comment: What browser/platform are you having this problem on?  If iOS, the only way around it is to use the Web Audio API.

Comment: Please be more careful with capitalization. This is not supposed to be a throwaway post in Reddit, but a long-lasting resource. Use a tool like Grammarly to correct your writing.